# Relationship not defined with my pgsql Join

Tags: postgresql

I am new to this and haven't been able to find the proper syntax for my table join...

```
SELECT
DISTINCT on (date (billing.starttime))
medias.name,
date (billing.starttime),
Count(distinct (billing.starttime)) as "# Plays",
Count(distinct(billing.playerid)) as "# Stores"

FROM
public.billing,
public.medias

JOIN ????? on billing.mediaitemid = medias.id

WHERE
medias.name LIKE any (array['COMM_7032%']) and
billing.starttime >= date('2017-04-26') and 
billing.starttime < date('2017-05-01') 

GROUP BY
date (billing.starttime),
medias.name

ORDER BY
date (billing.starttime)
```

I am not sure what fits where the ????? are. Everything that I have tried states that the relationship does not exist.

Comment: Please show us your complete query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should go:

```
...
FROM
public.billing JOIN public.medias on billing.mediaitemid = medias.id
WHERE
...
```

the syntax is

```
[table1] join [table2] on [condition]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from
    public.billing b
    inner join
    public.medias m on b.mediaitemid = m.id
```